# How do I filter certain javascripts from running and not block them all on Drudge Report?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, javascript, adblock, noscript

How do I block this particular "auto refresh" script on Drudge Report from running in my Firefox browser on Windows XP?

```
var timer = setInterval("autoRefresh()", 1000 * 60 * 3); 
function autoRefresh(){self.location.reload(true);}
```

I have NoScript and AdblockPlus plugins installed, but neither of them explain how to filter out a particular script and keep it from running and leave the rest alone.  I don't want to stop all javascripts from running just the one listed below.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought you could stop the interval from running, but this will only work if you can get to the context of the **timer** variable.

```
/* your code in another file */
clearInterval(timer);
```

My next idea is to redefine the **autoRefresh** function. It looks like that may be able to be done because the interval is referring to autoRefresh in a string instead of using a function, like

```
setInterval(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 1000 * 60 * 3);
```

Anyway, you would have to redefine autoRefresh like this:

```
autoRefresh() { }
```